# Adicionar coluna ao SQL considerando algumas condições para ser valida

Tags: sql, oracle, select, pl-sql

Estou tentando juntar duas informações e não estou conseguindo.

Montei este SQL para me trazer apenas os produtos que foram comprados que possuiam um desconto por meio de um contrato.
Porém este desconto foi cadastrado para as categorias dos produtos, e dentro de cada categoria eu tenho varias familias de produtos, logo dentro de cada familia eu tenho finalmente os produtos.

Desta forma eu montei um SQL que ficou assim.

`SELECT A.NUMERONF, A.NROEMPRESA, A.SEQPRODUTO
   FROM MLF_NFITEM A
WHERE A.SEQPRODUTO IN (SELECT SEQPRODUTO FROM MAP_PRODUTO 
WHERE SEQFAMILIA IN (SELECT SEQFAMILIA FROM MAP_FAMDIVCATEG 
WHERE SEQCATEGORIA IN (SELECT SEQCATEGORIA FROM MGC_CONTRATOCATEGORIA)));`

Supondo que este SQL tenha me gerado o seguinte resultado.

|NUMERONF| - |NROEMPRESA| - |SEQPRODUTO|

525 - 3 - 25085
525 - 3 - 25087
525 - 3 - 25088
525 - 3 - 25095
525 - 3 - 25097
525 - 3 - 25099
525 - 3 - 25105

Agora eu preciso adicionar uma coluna neste SQL que é o PERCENTUAL de desconto que cada produto teve ao dar entrada.

Porém a minha dificuldade vem agora...

Tenho 3 tabelas que contém as informações do contrato.

- MGC_CONTRATO - Ela me diz qual é o fornecedor deste contrato (Preciso adicionar ela na consulta para poder associar o fornecedor do contrato com o fornecedor da nota, mas isto é facil)
- MGC_CONTRATODESCONTO - Ela me diz qual percentual de desconto que foi cadastrado (Detalhe, dentro de um contrato posso ter mais de um percentual de desconto, cada um para uma ou mais categorias)
- MGC_CONTRATOCATEGORIA - Ela me diz quais categorias estão vinculadas ao seu respectivo desconto.

Então por exemplo,

- Eu tenho um contrato (SEQCONTRATO) numero 10
- Dentro deste SEQCONTRATO numero 10 eu tenho cinco percentuais diferentes (SEQDESCONTO) 1%, 2%, 3%, 4% e 5% (cada um com um SEQDESCONTO diferente)
- E dentro de cada SEQDESCONTO eu tenho as categorias vinculadas.

Agora eu preciso saber como colocar no meu SQL o percentual deste determinado produto.
Sendo que o percentual foi cadastrado na categoria...
Dentro da categoria tenho varias familias (essas duas informações eu tenho na tabela MAP_FAMDIVCATEG)
Dentro de cada familia eu tenho os produtos (tenho isso dentro da tabela MAP_PRODUTO)

Comment: Pensou em uma FUNCTION que recebesse cliente e produto e retorne o respectivo desconto ?

Comment: Como ficaria essa FUNCTION? E como eu aplicaria ela na minha consulta?

Comment: Na function você montaria a lógica do calculo do desconto a sql chamaria esta function , a vantagem da function é que torna uma regra complexa em uma simples coluna de sql , um exemplo em https://imasters.com.br/artigo/1754/oracle/examinando-alguns-exemplos-pl-sql/?trace=1519021197&source=single